# ViewBag.NameSortParm not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a Countries controller that simply deals with a list of countries with their corresponding Ids. In my view page, only the list of `CountryName` is displayed.

I want to achieve sorting, with sort order as **DESCENDING** by clicking on the Column Header in my view page but it's not working.

Here's my Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
{
    ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
    var countries = from c in db.Countries
                    select c;

    if (ViewBag.NameSortParm == "name_desc")
        countries = countries.OrderByDescending(c => c.CountryName);
    else
        countries = countries.OrderBy(c => c.CountryName);

    return View(db.Countries.ToList());
}
```

Here's my view part:

```
<h2>List of EU Member States</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Country Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountryName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

The table `Country` contains only 2 columns: `ID` as int Primary Key and is_identity = 1, and `CountryName` as varchar(100) Not Null.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Please use Debugger to make sure its not a simple coding error.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Rohit I've posted this question **after** debugging.

Comment: Didn't `countries` give you what you are expecting while debugging?

Comment: I was not returning `countries` to my index page that's why I couldn't figure out the problem after debugging.

Comment: I only suggested that it was an easy catch if you did debug through the code.

Comment: @Rohit Ok. I'll try to be more attentive while debugging. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Index()` method returns the original values from the database because you use

```
return View(db.Countries.ToList());
```

You need to return the sorted collection

```
return View(countries.ToList());
```

Comment: What is the difference between db.Countries.ToList() and countries.ToList()?

Comment: `db.Countries` is the collection from your database while `countries` is your sorted collection.